# Time based copy of row from Sheet2 to Sheet1, values copied to be kept over period of time

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 Sheets in a workbook, Sheet 1 contains permanent data, Sheet2 has information coming in using a DDE add-in.(esignal).

The data has Columns: Date, Time, Price

The time interval is 5 min.(Others are also possible but this is the one I am using for analysis)

The DDE gives the data from say row: 1 to 20. The value of the last row gets deleted once a new time period gets over i.e. if 7:00 PM is the top row(Row 1) "Time" then soon as time becomes :7:00:01, the 7:00PM row will become(Row2), Row1 will become 7:05 PM. 
And the last row(20) will be deleted and replaced with Row 19 data.

Assume the last time in Sheet1 is 6:55 PM, I want to get the final value for time 7:00, i.e. as soon as time moves to 7:00:01, from Sheet2(where DDE is giving the values) to Sheet1 below 6:55PM.

I wonder what would be the right way to do this, is VBA the correct language to learn to do this in the future? I am new and still in the learning process.

Tried the following(changes):

```
Sub Activate_timer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "MoveData"
End Sub

Sub MoveData()

    Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkbook

    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy

    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A14340").Select

    mainworkBook.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

    Call Activate_timer

End Sub
```

Location in Under Modules Folder Module1

Comment: Added attempt at solving the problem with code used. Helped my simoco.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the worksheet events for this purpose. For example if you add this function to the  VBA sheet, it will be called whenever the data changes on the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' WHERE Tatget is a Range in which the change occurred
End Sub
```

So in this function you can handle changes of cells and find the desired change checking exactly what range on the worksheet changed. Is it right direction to help you?

For example this handler displays the modified range address. You can check whether it satisfies some conditions and if so, perform the necessary actions.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    MsgBox Target.address

    If (IfSatisfySomeConditions(Target.address)) Then
        'do something
    End If
End Sub

Function IfSatisfySomeConditions(address As String) As Boolean
    'check condition and return result'

    IfSatisfySomeConditions = True
End Function
```

---

---

another approach is to use timer:

```
Sub Activate_timer()
    Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:05:00"), "doSomething"
End Sub

Sub doSomething()
    'do something
    Call Activate_timer
End Sub
```

this code trigger doSomething sub every 5 minutes

Comment: I dont think it will work in the way I want it to. The sheet in which the DDE is giving data, the top row keeps changing as and when a price change occurs on the exchange till the time period gets over, at which point it becomes permanent and moves to the next Row. So the data keeps changing.

Comment: I've add another approach to my answer

Comment: 1) you need to declare you variable. Try write **Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkbook** in the MoveData. 2) it is better to call timer at the end of the MoveData sub

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I changed it around,    Write Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkook I also tried:    Set mainworkBook = ThisWorkBook. First one gives: Compile Error, Syntax Error. Second one: Run-time error '13': Type Mismatch

Comment: and replace **.Row(3).EntireRow.Copy** with **.Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy**

Comment: this works for me:  `Sub MoveData()


ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4").Rows(3).EntireRow.Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A3811").Select
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Paste

Call Activate_timer

End Sub
`

Comment: Thanks :) Works now. I have a few more things to work out for this project. Great community here, thank you for all the help. Cheers

Comment: uhhh....hiccup, sorry to trouble you again. I tried using the macro in another workbook. Changed the references and it works when I run the macro using the ribbon. But it wont change after 5 mins elapse, when I run the macro using the ribbon it changes again.

Comment: I've added `MsgBox "Hello"` to the **MoveData** sub and changed timer to tick every 3 seconds, and the message appears every 3 sec as it should be. If you have opened several workbooks, try to close all but one. The fact is that if several books opened, then there may be problems with reference to the function "MoveData" in the sub **Activate_timer**, as in this case it is necessary to specify the fully qualified name "MyWorkbookName!MoveData" as it shown in the ribbon when you try to call some macros from another workbook.

Comment: uhhh...I can't seem to find the changed code that you have mentioned. Not sure about where to add "MyWorkbookName!MoveData". Strangely enough it started functioning properly after I saved changed and re-opened the file. Would still be great to make the changes if it makes the code better.

Comment: Hi Made a new question post to help clarify everything. Thanks. I hope you can give some time on that thread, I learned a lot from your code and would be great to learn more from you.

Comment: It's great that it works) I think you shouldn't make any changes with "MyWorkbookName!MoveData" if it works without it)